# How can I set up SSO with Azure AD and our back end strapi?

Tags: azure-active-directory, strapi

I am wondering if anyone has done this before,

I have an azure Active Directory, and I host the front end of our app in IIS. The back is controlled by pm2. How can I set up SSO with Azure AD and our back end strapi?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strapi supports natively Microsoft SSO.

You must act on three fronts: Azure Portal, Strapi Admin, Frontend App

#### 1 - AZURE Portal: (create application, configure, get params)

**1.1** Create application, go to the [App registrations](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade) site and register an app

**1.2** Click New Registration

**1.3** Fill the form as show in below ScreenShot

[image]

**1.3.1** In "Supported account types" set Multitenant option (in strapi, single tenant is not supported by default, if you need to set single tenant you must create a custom provider, but multitenant is ok)

**1.3.2** In the Redirect URI field, put "Web" and

> **/connect/microsoft/callback**

```
(i.e. http://localhost:1337/connect/microsoft/callback or your strapi
production url https://mystrapiexample.com/connect/microsoft/callback)
```

**1.3.3** Register and go to next page

**1.4** Go to the "Authentication" page of your registered App (left menu) to enable the implicit grant flow (Access tokens)

[image: enable implicit grant flow]

**1.5** Go to the "Certificate and secrets" page of your registered App (left menu) to create a "New client secret" and annotate the value, You will use it when you configure the provider on strapi.

**1.6** Also note the "Application (client) ID" in the Overview page, You will use it when you configure the provider on strapi

#### 2 - STRAPI ADMIN: (create application, configure, get params)

**2.1** Go to "Roles and Permission" > Providers > Microsoft

**2.2** Set Enable "ON" and your clientId and secret that you get in previous steps (1.5 and 1.6)

**2.3** The redirect URI to your front-end app which gets and redirects the microsoft access_code (this step will be clearer later)

[image]

#### 3 - FRONTEND APP:

Ready? At this point the flow begins, starts to jump to complete the authentication and obtain a strapi jwt to make the requests as an authenticated user.

**3.1** Create a link in your frontend application to strapi microsoft sign-in

> **/connect/microsoft**

```
(i.e. http://localhost:1337/connect/microsoft or your strapi
production url https://mystrapiexample.com/connect/microsoft)
```

**3.2** Strapi redirects the user to microsoft authentication page, on success the user will be redirected on strapi with a microsoft access_code (this step is transparent for you)

**3.3** Strapi redirects the access_code to the frontend url set in 2.3, which must redirect (with access_code) to strapi page auth

> **/auth/microsoft/callback**

```
(i.e http://localhost:1337/auth/microsoft/callback or your strapi
production url https://mystrapiexample.com/auth/microsoft/callback ).....
```

**3.4** At this point strapi creates its own JWT token which returns to the frontend application, which can store it (in localstorage, session storage...) to make requests to the strapi endpoints.

References

- https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/blob/master/login-react/doc/microsoft_setup.md
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer. exactly what i needed

Comment: Hi mike, I have updated the flow described in step 3.

Comment: Pay attention if you are behind a proxy you could get a buffer proxy error (i.e.: "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream" in this case adjust your proxy buffer), with nginx this fixes:
```
            proxy_buffer_size          128k;
            proxy_buffers              4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
```
I spent a couple of hours trying to figure it out

Comment: I used this walk through for my local dev and it worked, now it doesnt work for production, i believe i need to set up a proxy, do you have a walkthrough for that? Just wondering as your last one was awesome

Comment: Hi @fiblan, I am having some trouble with this. I followed it exactly but I keep getting an error from Microsoft saying "AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute URI." Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement authentication using Azure AD in your strapi CRM web project.

**Steps to follow:**

1. [Register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) in Azure AD.
2. Add target API, and grant consent to select [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration).
3. Choose your Microsoft authentication library ,recommended [MSAL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal)
4. Implement the [MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso)  in your project. It is very [simple to implement](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client) and code sample that can help you is available [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-auth-code).

Please let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Hello @Hari Krishna is there a way I can pass through the built in strapi user info and not have to use the MSAL?

Comment: Hi @Mike,I am not sure about  'built in strapi user info' but you can implement autentication by using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/active-directory-authentication-libraries)  as an alternative to MSAL.