# Strapi Microsoft authentication having issue with Redirect URI in Angular app

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, strapi

I have followed the guide detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137923/how-can-i-set-up-sso-with-azure-ad-and-our-back-end-strapi). Everything is set up with the App Registration, Strapi Provider config, and in the MSAL configuration. Whenever the auth flow begins, I get sent to a Microsoft login screen, I log in, and I get a Microsoft error saying `AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute URI.`. I. am currently running Strapi and Angular on localhost.

I have added `http://localhost:1337/connect/microsoft/callback` to the Web Redirect URI list in the App Registration. The error screen url shows the Redirect URI being sent is. `redirect_uri=%2Fconnect%2Fmicrosoft%2Fcallback`. This does not seem to be valid.

Strapi admin Microsoft config has a field that says `The redirect URL to add in your Microsoft application configurations` with the value `/connect/microsoft/callback` which isn't editable. Is there where the auth is looking to pass the uri?  If so, how can it be changed? If not, what is the proper way to configure this. I have not found any official documentation on how to configure this.

Comment: Hi do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is there any other concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url` in `my-project/config/server.js` is required to use the connect feature. But the document is not so clear.

You can add the `url` as `http://localhost:1337` into `my-project/config/server.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env('ADMIN_JWT_SECRET', '38506ed8f48446c253135d43bbc2afec'),
    },
  },
  url: 'http://localhost:1337'
});
```

It will add `http://localhost:1337` before `/connect/microsoft/callback`, which should be able to fix this issue. More discussion [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/issues/159#issuecomment-650377973) and [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6570#issuecomment-644687640).

Besides, if your `localhost` has been changed before due to some other configuration, you can add the specific host with port here like this: `url: 'http://10.10.100.242:1337'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes this did solve my issue. If you don't mind, can I PM with a related issue?

Comment: @andrewxt Sure. Show your issue pls.

Comment: Do you mind looking at this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399724/invalid-audience-from-strapi-microsoft-provider-callback-request-in-angular-ap