# 'Invalid audience' from Strapi Microsoft provider callback request in Angular app

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, strapi

I am trying to configure authentication using Microsoft in an Angular app. I am able to authenticate in the app successfully. When I send the token I receive to `http://localhost:1337/auth/microsoft/callback?access_token=${token}` I get a response back saying 'Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.' I checked the token I am sending in jwt.io and the audience matches the client id configured in the Strapi admin config for the Microsoft provider. Am I missing a step?

My request looks like this and is fired after auth is complete and the token is set.

`` let token = window.localStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken') this.http.get(http://localhost:1337/auth/microsoft/callback?access_token=${token}`) .subscribe((res) => { console.log(res); }); ``

EDIT:

Token decoded:
[image]

Azure App Registration:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Strapi Config:

[image]

EDIT:

Did not realize the access token was separate from the idToken. After digging through the network tab, I found the actual one and posted below. Calling this api to Strapi gets back a valid token. So it appears to be working. But I don't know how to retrieve this token programatically in the front end as it is being called as a Redirect URI. Is there a common strategy for capturing it from the url before it disappears to save in storage?

Accesstoken:

[image]

Permissions:

[image]

Comment: Show the permission you configured in Azure AD app and a screenshot of the decoded access token in jwt.io.

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshots

Comment: The screenshot you provided is for ID token rather than Access token. Please check it. I need the decoded result for Access token. Besides, I also need a screenshot of the permissions you configured in Azure AD app. You should find it from **API permissions** under your App registrations app.

Comment: Thanks, I added more information. The actual access token works but I'm not sure how to retrieve it because it redirects off of that page quickly. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi are you still looking for help on this issue? Does the answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I find that you get the id token and use it to access your api, as you mentioned,it will raise 'Access token fail. Invalid audience.' error.You should use an access token to access your api.

For your question, Do you want to programmatically get access token?If so,you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular).

The code usually like this:

```
getToken() {
        const accessTokenRequest = {
             scopes: [
                 "your api url",
             ],
            clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/(tenant)ID or tenant name",
            redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200",
        };
        this.authService
            .acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("acquireTokenPopup");
                this.token = res.accessToken;
                this.getUser();
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log("acquireTokenPopup catch");
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
```

And if you just want to store access token:

To save a string in Local Storage you use

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

You can get the value later with:

```
window.localStorage.getItem(key);
```

window.localStorage.setItem('access_token',token);
window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');

hope it helps  you.